# Given a Perl DateTime object, how do I output "1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th of the month"

Tags: perl, datetime, formatting

I can't find a `DateTime::Format::` module that outputs the day of the month properly.
e.g. Using `DateTime->strftime` instead of outputting "19 July", I want to output "19th July".

[DateTime::Format::Natural::Lang::EN](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aNatural%3a%3aLang%3a%3aEN) *parses* dates like that, but I need the opposite - an output formatter.

I don't want to use Date::Calc or any other date module (but would consider non-date modules), and I don't want to have to write it myself.

For reference: [DateTime docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime), where the [strftime patterns](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#strftime-Patterns) don't appear to include "1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th", etc.

Comment: I remembered this is called the "ordinal", and there's some custom code in this [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369907/how-do-i-retrieve-an-integers-ordinal-suffix-in-perl-like-st-nd-rd-th). I'd still like a DateTime format module to achieve this though.

Comment: http://p3rl.org/Lingua::EN::Numbers::Ordinate

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could write some kind of custom formatter (and then release it to CPAN!) This gets you some of the way there...

```
package DateTime::Ordinated;

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'DateTime';
use Lingua::EN::Numbers::Ordinate;

sub day {
  my $self = shift;

  my $day = $self->SUPER::day;

  return ordinate($day);
}

1;
```

And to test...

```
$ perl -MDateTime::Ordinated -E'$d=DateTime::Ordinated->now;say $d->day'
19th
```